# Receiving the same error Invariant Violation on two npm packages react-native-blur and react-native-linear-gradient

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I've followed the correct instructions on installing, linking (manually), tried deleting node_modules, build, watchman del, and reinstalling, downgrading to react-native 0.51.0, but I continuously get the same error:

on react-native 0.52.0, latest build for both of these (react-native-blur is "^3.2.2")

[image]

Really stumped as I don't know what else to do.

EDIT: Ran this, didn't work:

```
npm install react-native-svg --save //(again)
react-native link react-native-svg //(again)
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && yarn install
```

Then in another terminal

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```